# AWS cloudFormation LAMP stack fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

While creating a LAMP stack using a predefined *AWS CloudFormation* template,
I'm getting an error, due to which the stack creation is rolled back.

[image: cloudFormation Error]
I'm unable to understand the error message.

[Here](https://s3-ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-templates-ap-south-1/LAMP_Multi_AZ.template) is the template for that LAMP stack that I was trying to create; I have just changed Instance volume `t2-micro` in this.

Would appreciate any help in getting this resolved.

Comment: Are you sure you've shared the same template you used? I didn't find any resource of type 'AWS::EC2::Instance' defined in that template.

Comment: Yes I am using the same template , This temp is from sample template of AWS lamp basic 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/sample-templates-appframeworks-us-west-2.html

Comment: The link that you shared in question was for template name: 'LAMP stack scalable and durable', the link that you just shared in the comment above was for 'LAMP stack basic'.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming by 'instance volume' you mean 'instance type'?
Looks like a typo; `t2-micro` should really be `t2.micro` (*i.e.* a dot rather than hyphen).

Comment: Yes , I used the same "t2.micro", but unable to understand the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this script
https://github.com/benishak/lamp-aws-cloudformation

With it you can deploy any PHP App like Wordpress or your own application. you can specify your application source code and it will be deployed to the instances

I think your error is caused due to failing health check, this can due to misconfigurations in Network ACL or Security Group or missing NATGateway for private subnet. Or the instances is returning error like HTTP 4xx or 5xx, or 3xx. this could be a problem in the deployed app itself. Make sure the deployed code is returning 200 and make sure you specify the write health check path

Try using the above script, it will create a new VPC with all configurations and resources you need.